# check and add multiple lines in puppet

Tags: puppet

I need to ensure through puppet that the file `/etc/logrotate.conf` must have the entry

```
/var/log/secure {
    monthly
    rotate 11
}
```

I tried

```
$line_string = "/var/log/secure {
    monthly
    rotate 11
}"

file_line {'ensure correct entry in /etc/logrotate.conf':
  path  => '/etc/logrotate.conf',
  line  => $line_string,
  match => $line_string,
}
```

It creates the entry the first time, but when I apply the puppet code a second time it adds the entry again

```
[~] # puppet apply /home/vijay/logrot.pp
Notice: Compiled catalog for lxv9824 in environment production in 0.10 seconds
/var/lib/puppet/lib/puppet/provider/file_line/ruby.rb:36: warning: regexp has invalid interval
/var/lib/puppet/lib/puppet/provider/file_line/ruby.rb:36: warning: regexp has `}' without escape
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File_line[ensure correct entry in /etc/logrotate.conf]/ensure: created
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.06 seconds

[~] # more /etc/logrotate.conf
/var/log/secure {
    monthly
    rotate 11
}
/var/log/secure {
    monthly
    rotate 11
}
```

How can I prevent puppet from adding the entry a second time?

Comment: Have you considered placing a file in /etc/logrotate.d instead?

Answer (score 3):

The `file_line` resource from `puppetlabs-stdlib` is not idempotent when the `line` attribute has newlines in its parameter. You could do something about this with the `match` attribute, but the regexp you supplied is invalid (note the warnings from `file_line.rb`).

Since it appears that the `/etc/logrotate.conf` contains only that entry, you could do:

```
file { '/etc/logrotate.conf':
  ensure  => file,
  content => $line_string,
}
```

or you could do (with non-obsolete puppet and future parser if 3.8.x):

```
['/var/log/secure {', '    monthly', '    rotate 11', '}'].each |$line| {
  file_line { "ensure $line in /etc/logrotate.conf":
    path  => '/etc/logrotate.conf',
    line  => $line,
    match => $line,
  }
}
```

or you could use augeas, which I personally loathe, but let me know if you need more options.

There are also modules to concatenate onto files like this one: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-concat

You could also try fixing your regexp, starting with the two warnings:

```
$line_string_regexp = "/var/log/secure \{
    monthly
    rotate 11
\}"
```

You have a lot of options here to be honest.

Comment: file_line does the `match` and `line` operation line by line. Even a valid multiple line regex is given to file_line, it would not lead to a valid match and replace. In return it appends $line repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention it (I just missed this coming from ansible), ***ansible*** has a [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html) option

> ```
> - name: Insert/Update eth0 configuration stanza in /etc/network/interfaces
>         (it might be better to copy files into /etc/network/interfaces.d/)
>   ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
>     path: /etc/network/interfaces
>     block: |
>       iface eth0 inet static
>           address 192.0.2.23
>           netmask 255.255.255.0
> ```

In this case, a solution would be

> placing a file in /etc/logrotate.d

as suggested in [check and add multiple lines in puppet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539178/check-and-add-multiple-lines-in-puppet/75461930#comment64485702_38539178).

In other cases, you can e.g. write yaml and json as single-line strings: [Yaml - how to write mapping(s) in single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67643263/yaml-how-to-write-mappings-in-single-line) .