# file_line appends data on every puppet run

Tags: puppet

```
file_line { '/etc/profile.d/setjvmparams.sh':
  path => '/etc/profile.d/setjvmparams.sh',
  line => "export JAVA_HOME=/usrdata/apps/java/${tomcat::jdkversion}\nexport JRE_HOME=/usrdata/apps/java/${tomcat::jdkversion}/jre\nexport PATH=\"/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:\$JAVA_HOME/bin\"",
}
```

This is appending the data each time. As far as I read, `file_line` was designed to add data only if it did not exist in the file. How to make sure, it gets added only when not present?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539178/check-and-add-multiple-lines-in-puppet/38541904

Comment: I don't completely understand that answer. Do you suggest that 
`file { '/etc/logrotate.conf':
  ensure  => file,
  content => $line_string,
}
` 
this could work if I put the text corresponding to `line` in `$line_string` ?

Answer (score 0):

The file_line type should be used for single lines, but the `line` parameter you're passing has three lines separated with `\n`. This should be split into three resources:

```
file_line { '/etc/profile.d/setjvmparams.sh JAVA_HOME':
  path => '/etc/profile.d/setjvmparams.sh',
  line => "export JAVA_HOME=/usrdata/apps/java/${tomcat::jdkversion}",
}

file_line { '/etc/profile.d/setjvmparams.sh JRE_HOME':
  path => '/etc/profile.d/setjvmparams.sh',
  line => "export JRE_HOME=/usrdata/apps/java/${tomcat::jdkversion}/jre",
}

file_line { '/etc/profile.d/setjvmparams.sh PATH':
  path => '/etc/profile.d/setjvmparams.sh',
  line => "export PATH=\"/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:\$JAVA_HOME/bin\"",
}
```

Comment: is it not matching the whitespaces?